# Handling '?' in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a page that asks a user to confirm if he wants to continue or cancel and I use a rewrite rule for it:

```
RewriteRule ^click/(.+)$ aclick.php?url=$1 [B]
```

The problem arises when the URL has a question mark. For example:

```
http://example.com/click/yahoo.com/mobile/?s=ladygaga
```

My goal is that this URL be re-written as:

```
http://example.com/aclick.php?url=yahoo.com/mobile/%3fs=ladygaga
```

So that the continue button will proceed to: 'http://yahoo.com/mobile/?s=ladygaga'

However, the continue button is just linked to 'http://yahoo.com/mobile/'.

Does anyone have an idea to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%{QUERY_STRING}` as follows.  You have to refer `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING` instead of `QUERY_STRING`.

```
RewriteRule ^click/(.+) aclick.php?url=$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [B,L]
```

`B` flag will escape the string excessively.  If you access `http://example.com/click/yahoo.com/mobile/?s=ladygaga`, the query string will be `url=yahoo%2ecom%2fmobile%2f?s=ladygaga`.  (It does not cause bad influence.)

In case that URL have no query string, redundant "?" is added to the end of query string. To prevent this, use `RewriteCond`:

```
# If URL have any query string, then
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^click/(.+) aclick.php?url=$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [B,L]
# otherwise,
RewriteRule ^click/(.+) aclick.php?url=$1
```

---

You can simply written as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^click/(.+) aclick.php
```

Program aclick.php can refer environment variables `REQUEST_URI`, `REDIRECT_URL`, `QUERY_STRING` etc.